# Is there way in Adobe Acrobat to remove a stroked object with same dimensions as the page's trim box?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

On occasion, I receive PDF files (with bleed) that have a rectangle with a stroke along the trim box. Usually, these lines are a unique spot color, which is easy to select and remove.

However, the last file I received has the line using black ink:
[image: Screenshot of this issue].

This prompted me to wonder if there was a way to select and remove objects with a stroke, no fill, that match the dimensions of the trim box, and that have the same origin point (lower left corner if I am not mistaken).

I have looked through the preflight settings and cannot come up with anything that would allow me to do this. However, it is also possible that I missed something. I'm also open to doing a javascript action, but am not sure where to start with that.

I'm interested in some type of automated solution, since often these files could be hundreds of pages in length, and the page dimensions are not all the same.

Also, I am aware that I could just ask for a new file, but in some cases, a new file is not available.

I'm open to solutions that involve anything available by default in Acrobat DC (actions/preflight/etc.) as well as Enfocus Pitstop (since I have access to this plugin as well). However, my preference would be Acrobat Preflight first, and then Acrobat action second.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect there is no way to do this as automatically as I had hoped.

Acrobat actions (javascript) can easily find the trim size, but it has no ability to find objects/shapes that only have a stroke. Preflight can find objects of a specific size, but the variables (if used) have to be entered at runtime and cannot reference elements of the document. (Pitstop appears to have the same limitations as Acrobat Preflight.) :(

Comment: @KJ I'll try it out. However, it is not the cropBox/TrimBox/etc that I want to remove. Instead, it is a rectangle object in the document that matches the size/dimensions of the trimBox. (This rectangle will print, while the PDF page-boxes won't).

Comment: Here's a link to a two page document with all the text removed. The dark gray box is what I am wanting to target.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gp8P4j5Me_9__YHiW1kGrpCxa55aczRo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Agreed. I tweaked with the qpdf option and uncompressed the document. However, I ran into issues knowing exactly how much to delete. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found that I can make the rectangles "disappear" by changing the `33.15 33.15 341.7 503.7` to `00.00 00.00 000.0 00.00`. It appears that the number of characters in the line matters, but the numbers themselves can be changed. Technically, the rectangles still exist at the 0-point, but they are not within the trimbox anymore meaning they will not cause a problem when printed at our printshop.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

While it went much deeper than I thought it needed to, I found a solution that I can build off of:

Using a tool like `qpdf` or `pdftk`, uncompress the document structure.

Next, search for a line that begins with `/Trimbox` to extract out the Trim Box dimensions. (I used `pdftk` for this part. If you use `qpdf`, then you will want to look at the numbers on the next four lines.) Since these numbers are based on a point-based ruler with the zero-point being on the Media Box, to get the actual width/height of the rectangle, you will need to subtract the last two numbers from the first two: `[2]-[0]` for the width. `[3]-[1]` for the height.

Next is a slightly tricky part. In a perfect world, the Trim Box width and height will match the rectangle exactly. However, since there is a stroke applied, the number will be a little different—specifically it will have decimals.

Parsing the file line by line, I look for lines that the second number starts with the Trim Box origin number `[1]` from the above paragraph and end with the letters `re`. (This document has bleeds and facing pages, which means that rectangles from the facing page will be included in the center bleed area, making the first number variable.) In my file, the regex search string looked like this:  `33.*re\n` (with a leading space)

I then capture the length of the line (characters) and replace it with `0 0 0 0           re` (padding the section of the line prior to the `re` with the exact number of spaces to keep the character length of the line the same as the original. Yes this matters.)

After saving the file, I have a file that has removed all rectangle boxes that match the trim box size, and that match one axis of the Trim Box edge.

I suspect that as time goes on, I could get fancier with the script and process. I also suspect that there are plenty of gotchas in this process. However, this process will work well for me for now.

Thanks `@K-J` for your help and pointing me in this direction.

---

A less automated approach uses Pitstop Actions and variables. One could create and action with two "select size" filters connected with an "AND" and specify a variable for the Trim and Height. Then you can "Remove Selection"

When the script runs, it will ask for a width and height, and then remove all the objects it finds.

Unfortunately, Pit Stop (and Acrobat itself) cannot create variables that are based on page boxes.